# In shell script, how do I use the contents of a file as a parameter

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose in `dir.txt` I have the following content:

`test-dir`

I try to use that as a parameter as follows:

`echo dir.txt | cp * $1`

I want the above to be the equivalent of:

`cp * test-dir`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are giving the string "dir.txt" to a program that does not accept any input by stdin.

You are looking for the following syntax:

```
cp * "$(<dir.txt)"
```

`$()` runs the command inside parenthesis and substitutes its results in its position in the command line. The `<` is a shorthand to read a file (a `cat` would also work). The quotes are to avoid problems with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can get content of file to variable:

```
file1=$(cat dir.txt)
echo $file1
```

Results:

```
test-dir
```